# How do I display the result of this SQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, distinct

I can't figure out how to display the result of this query in PHP/MySql. I would like to use a prepared statement if possible.

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT(video_view_ip) ) FROM video_views
```

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to display results of SQL queries in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fetch data from sql and print it using php please use this way

first connect to databse

```
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password");
                if (!$con)
                {
                     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                mysqli_select_db($con,"db_name");
```

and after connects, retrieve data from table

```
                $sql_fetch_vide_count = "SELECT count( DISTINCT(video_view_ip) ) as video_count FROM video_views ";
                $video_result = $con->query($sql_fetch_vide_count);
                if (!$video_result) {
                    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
                }

                //getting the date to array
                $row_video = $video_result->fetch_assoc();

                //Fetch the count result
                $video_count = isset($row_video ['video_count ']) ? $row_video ['video_count '] : 0;
```

if you fetching all the data from database then use

```
                $array_videos = array();
                while ($row_video = $video_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $array_videos [] = $row_video ;
                }
```

you can get all the data into the $array_videos as an array

Comment: Thanks, using "as video_count" in the sql is what I needed to know!

Answer (score 0):

First, we will need to acquire a connection to the database. For this, we will be using PDO:

```
<?php

$config = [
  'driver'   => 'mysql',
  'host'     => 'localhost',     // replace this with the actual mysql host if needed
  'port'     => 3306,            // default mysql port is 3306
  'database' => 'my_database',   // replace this with the database you are using
  'username' => 'admin',         // replace this with your username
  'password' => 'password',      // replace this with your password
];

$connection = new PDO(
  vsprintf('%s:Server=%s,%s;Database=%s', [
    $config['driver'],
    $config['host'],
    $config['port'],
    $config['database'],
  ]),
  $config['username'],
  $config['password']
);
```

To keep the configuration private, you may store this in a separate file that is read-only. You may then read this configuration with `parse_ini_file`.

To run the query, and store the results we will have to do the following:

```
// in this case, we can use fetchColumn to retrieve the count, since it is a single value. However, we will usually want to use fetch() for most cases.
$count = $connection
  ->query('SELECT count( DISTINCT(video_view_ip) ) FROM video_views')
  ->fetchColumn();
```

To display the results, we can simply `echo` them out:

```
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this for example on how to produce your output on php page
EDITED: Added prepared statement prior to OP request

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

// set parameters and execute
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

$firstname = "Mary";
$lastname = "Moe";
$email = "mary@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

$firstname = "Julie";
$lastname = "Dooley";
$email = "julie@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```